# How to join tables in SQL by ID in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have the following tables:

**countryregion**

```
CountryRegionCode | Name                 
------------------------------------------
AD                | Andorra
AE                | United Arab Emirates
AR                | Argentina
------------------------------------------
```

**currency**

```
CurrencyCode      | Name                 
------------------------------------------
AED               | Emirati Dirham
ARS               | Argentine Peso
ALL               | Lek
------------------------------------------
```

**countryregioncurrency**

```
CountryRegionCode | CurrencyCode                
------------------------------------------
AE                | AED
AR                | ARS
------------------------------------------
```

How would I combine them such that the rows are interconnected like below:

```
Name                 | Name
------------------------------------------
United Arab Emirates | Emirati Dirham
Argentina            | Argentino Peso
------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use two joins, where the `countryregioncurrency` table is used as a mapping table:

```sql
SELECT cr.name, c.name
FROM   countryregion cr
JOIN   countryregioncurrency crc ON cr.countryregioncode = crc.countryregioncode
JOIN   currency c ON c.currencycode = crc.currencycode
```